# Hibernate is throwing managed flush exception

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, sequence

We are trying to save entity in Oracle : **Oracle Database 11g** Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

We are using **Hibernate** for same:

We are getting following distinct error:

```
o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Detailed relevant stacktrace is as below:

```
[ERROR]--- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.PK_USER_FAVORITE) violated
 [WARN ]  --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
[ERROR] --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException**: could not execute statement]
[ERROR] --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.mastercard.refarch.aop.ServiceLogging : {"aop_service":"UserFavoritesService", "method":"addCurrentUserFavorite", "type":"failed", "error":"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [XXX.PK_USER_FAVORITE]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement", "args":"(["s029158",{"userFavoriteId":null,"applicationId":"XXX","functionAlphaCode":"SOME vale","title":"Service Report"}])"}
```

We are using **oracle sequence** for generating primary key value. I guess we are getting above issue when oracle sequence is trying to execute. **Hibernate is failing to execute Oracle sequence whenever we get above exception**, Thats main smell here.

There is also **not null** and **primary key constraint** on Entity that we are trying to save on DB.

Current Hibernate Version is **Hibernate-core 5.2.17**
and version if hibernate JPA is **Hibernate-JPA-2.1-API-1.0.2.Final**

Still wondering why we are getting :

**Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is the error message which says `ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.PK_USER_FAVORITE) violated`. Apparently the unique constraint on your USER_FAVORITE table is being violated.

Check the sequence to see what its next value is, then check to see what the maximum value of this unique key column in the USER_FAVORITE table is. If the max value of the unique column is >= the next value from the sequence you'll have to fix things up.